# How to run a script when clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript

So, I have a javascript for a popunder ad, (yeah I know they're annoying but it's not an ad, it's a page that opens behind the main page) anyway, because the script has the page open automatically when you go to my page, pop up blockers automatically block it, so what I would like to do is have the script run when someone clicks a link on my page, therefore it is user initiated and not automatically, so it doesn't get blocked by a popup blocker.. basically, so when someone clicks on one of the links on my page, it opens the link, but also opens the pop under behind my page.. I'm kind of new to javascript, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Whats the `onClick` event for?

Comment: There isn't an onClick event, atleast I don't think so... http://www.2createawebsite.com/enhance/create-popunder.html is where I got the script from, so if you see anything in there that I didn't it would be really helpful

Answer (score 4):

This would be one approach:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="link">Link</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function script() {
    alert("I'm the ad");
};

document.getElementById('link').onclick = function () {
    script();
};
```

For demonstration see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHJ6u/1/).

**/Edit:** Sure, here is the JavaScript:

```
// copy and paste the script from the website

document.getElementById('open').onclick = function () {
    load_pop_power();
};
```

If you don't want to show the ad when the user visits the site, you could however delete half of the code.

Comment: Okay that seems to work out, but where do I put in my existing code and my new code that you have given me? If someone could PLEASE put it together for me using the link I gave in a comment above, I would be super greatful because I have barely any idea of what I'm doing.. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
function doSomething() {
    //do your actions here
    window.location="http://www.gotothelink.com";
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:doSomething();">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the link, the javascript code in the "onlick" attribute is executed. "window.open" opens a new window and "return true" has the effekt that the normal behaviour of the link keeps working.

```
<a href="http://www.tiscover.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.tiscover.com'); return true;">tiscover</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to bind the popunder to a click event on a link 
see http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/bind_event_in_js_object.htm